# How to match(unmatch) repositories in folder with find?

Tags: regex, linux, find, match

I has following command to find all standart files and folders:

```
find /home/user/ \( ! -path "*/\.*" \) \( ! -type l \)
```

This find matches all but dot files/dirs with it's content and symlinks.

Also I want to exclude my git and hg repositories entirely (both repo folder name and it's content) too.

I know about .git and .hg folder's. But I can't understand how to use this in regex.

Comment: It seems to me that your `-path "*/\.*"` should already apply to `.git` and `.hg`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /home/user  \! -type l | egrep -v '/\..*'
```

This will find all files which are not symlink and  grep will exclude any hidden file or hidden directory.